# Two Real Analysis Questions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, compactness, lp-spaces

If I have $ A = \{a \in \ell_2 : |a(n)| \leqslant c(n)\}$ for $c(n)\geqslant 0$ where $ n \in N $, and I want to show that is $A$ compact in $\ell_2$ iff $\sum{c(n)^2}<\infty$. How do I go about showing both directions?

If $f \in C(T)$ is the $1$-periodic continuous functions in $\Bbb R$, how to show $\lim \limits_{|n|\to\infty}\int_0^1 e^{-2\pi inx}f(x)=0 ?$ Also is this true if $f$ were in the closure of the set of 1-periodic step functions in $R$ Intuitively, I think the later is false since boundedness does not imply continuity.

Comment: @martini That is probably the right question.

Comment: I'm confused about some notation.  You say $\{a:\vert x(n)\vert\leq y(n)\}$.  Do you mean $\{a:\vert a(n)\vert\leq y(n)\}$?  Also, what is $c(n)$?  Do you mean $y(n)$ there?

Comment: @confused I suggest you split the question in two pieces.

Comment: @confused: if you register one of your accounts, they can be merged.

Comment: @robjohn: I always thought that accounts can be merged even without being registered.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (1): If $\sum c_n^2 < \infty$, show the set is closed and totally bounded. 
If $\sum c_n^2 = \infty$, show that the set is not bounded.

Hint for (2): Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, but you probably want to prove it yourself for trigonometric polynomials and also for indicator functions of intervals.

Comment: (1) Did you try to understand the hints?  Don't work directly with Cauchy sequences.

(2) Can you calculate the integral when $f(x) = \exp(2 \pi i k x)$ or the indicator function of an interval?

Comment: Okay so for (1) I think I can figure it out but for (2) I am trying to apply Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma but it means that I need to show $f(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable. I'm not given anything except its 1-period continuous and so I dont know how to show $\int f^- <\infty$ and $\int f^+ <\infty$. Another approach was to show that its Riemann integrable which implies Lebesgue integrable. How can I show that the upper and lower integrals equal each other? $\overline{\int f} =\underline{\int f}$

Comment: A continuous function on a closed, bounded interval is bounded and measurable and hence Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Your proof by compactness is wrong.  What you have to show is this:  if $c(n) \ge 0$ and $\sum_n c(n)^2 = \infty$, then for  any $B$ there is $a \in \ell_2$ with $|a(n)| \le c(n)$ for all $n$ and $\sum_n a(n)^2 \ge B$.

Comment: As for the reverse direction, $\ell_2$ is not compact.   Do you know what "totally bounded" means?

Comment: It's a contradiction because a compact set in a metric space is bounded.
No, that is not what totally bounded means.  Look it up.

Comment: OK, now try a nice finite collection of $x_i$'s, say those where each $x_i(n)$ is a multiple of $\delta$ and 
$x_i(n) = 0$ for $n > N$, for some $\delta$ and $N$.